# equivalent of DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap() in opensaml v3.x

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

As part of migrating from opensaml version 2.2.1 to 3.4.6,

> what is the equivalent of `DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap()` in opensaml version 3.x?